# Calling the method `to_i` in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Following is my Ruby code:

```
"100".to_i(9) # => 81
```

Can somebody explain why the result is `81`?

Answer (score 3):

Look into radix and the [`String#to_i` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i). It's the base. Normal numbers are base 10. You specified base 9.